# Dynamically remove rows in DOM table

Tags: javascript, dom, removechild

I am having trouble with the removeChild function in the loop below and couldnt really find good examples for it? what is wrong with my code?

```
    var univArray = new Array(
    {name: "Stanford University", nick: "Stanford", ownership: "private", sys: "n/a", SATh: 1550, SATl: 1360, tuition: 27204, room: 8680},
    {name: "University of California, Berkeley", nick: "UC Berkeley", ownership: "public", sys: "University of California", SATh: 1440, SATl: 1170, tuition: 4200, room: 10608},
    {name: "University of California, Santa Cruz", nick: "UC Santa Cruz", ownership: "public", sys: "University of California", SATh: 1270, SATl: 1030, tuition: 4384, room: 9708},
    {name: "San Francisco State University", nick: "SFSU", ownership: "public", sys: "CalState", SATh: 1120, SATl: 850, tuition: 1826, room: 6736},
    {name: "San Jose State University", nick: "SJSU", ownership: "public", sys: "CalState", SATh: 1140, SATl: 860, tuition: 1912, room: 7395},
    {name: "Sonoma State University", nick: "Sonoma State", ownership: "public", sys: "CalState", SATh: 1140, SATl: 930, tuition: 2226, room: 9606},
    {name: "California State University, Hayward", nick: "CalState Hayward", ownership: "public", sys: "CalState", SATh: 1050, SATl: 810, tuition: 1800, room: 6435},
    {name: "University of San Francisco", nick: "USF", ownership: "private", sys: "Roman Catholic", SATh: 1240, SATl: 1030, tuition: 21780, room: 9080},
    {name: "Santa Clara University", nick: "SCU", ownership: "private", sys: "Roman Catholic", SATh: 1300, SATl: 1110, tuition: 23445, room: 8904},
    {name: "Mills College", nick: "Mills College", ownership: "private", sys: "n/a", SATh: 1130, SATl: 920, tuition: 19482, room: 7832}
    );

    var table = document.createElement("table")
    document.body.appendChild(table)
    table.setAttribute("id", "tableid")
    var tbody = document.createElement("tbody")
    table.appendChild(tbody)
    var row = document.createElement("tr")
    tbody.appendChild(row)
    header =document.createElement("th")
    row.appendChild(header)
    header.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Name"))
    header =document.createElement("th")
    row.appendChild(header)
    header.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Sat High"))
    header =document.createElement("th")
    row.appendChild(header)
    header.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Sat Low"))
    header =document.createElement("th")
    row.appendChild(header)
    header.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Tuition"))
    header =document.createElement("th")
    row.appendChild(header)
    header.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Room and Board"))

        for (var i = 0; i < univArray.length; i++) {
            var tbody = document.createElement("tbody")
            table.appendChild(tbody)
            var row = document.createElement("tr")
            tbody.appendChild(row)

            cell = document.createElement("td")
            row.appendChild(cell)
            cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(univArray[i].name))
            cell = document.createElement("td")
            row.appendChild(cell)
            cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(univArray[i].SATh))
            cell = document.createElement("td")
            row.appendChild(cell)
            cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(univArray[i].SATl))
            cell = document.createElement("td")
            row.appendChild(cell)
            cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(univArray[i].tuition))
            cell = document.createElement("td")
            row.appendChild(cell)
            cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(univArray[i].room))
        }

    function filter(){
        if (document.getElementById("public").checked) {
            var nodes = document.body.getElementsByTagName('tr')
            for (var z = 0; z < univArray.length; z++) {
                var node = nodes[z];
                if (univArray[z].ownership != "public") {

                    node.parentNode.removeChild(node)
                }
            }
        }
    }



    document.getElementById("update").onclick = filter;
```

Comment: Can you explain what is happening when u execute the current code. If possible can you attach the complete i.e. the JSON code as well.

Comment: I am trying to loop through an array and remove the rows in the table that dont match the if statement in the function filter(). All the code has been added.

Answer (score 2):

`getElementsByTagName` returns a NodeList and as W3C says: "NodeList objects in the DOM are live.". This means when you remove a node from you DOM tree, it's also removed from your `nodes` list variable. So you need always remove the first element of your list:

```
var node = nodes[0];
if (univArray[z].ownership != "public") {
    node.parentNode.removeChild(node)
}
```

Comment: +1 for the important information. Now I could solve this/my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. I tried following your suggestion, but the if statement seems to be getting ignored. Here's what I have now:

```
function filter(){
   if (document.getElementById("public").checked) {
      var nodes = document.body.getElementsByTagName('tr')
      for (var z = 0; z <  nodes.length; z++) {
          var node = nodes[1];
          if (univArray[z].ownership != "public") {
              node.parentNode.removeChild(node)
          }
      }
   }
   if (document.getElementById("private").checked) {
      var nodes = document.body.getElementsByTagName('tr')
      for(var i=0; i <univArray.length; i++ ) {
          //Don't want to delete header row so we start at 1
          var node= nodes[1];
          if (univArray[i].ownership != "private") {
              node.parentNode.removeChild(node)
          }     
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Which If statement won't work? Also if you're skipping a row, then you should decrease the number of iterations, that is:  `for(var z=1;` and `for(var i=1;`

Comment: Both of them. It just deletes the first three columns.

Comment: Then it's hard to say what's wrong without all the code. I'd also try to replace `document.body.getElementsByTagName('tr')` with  `document.getElementById("tableid").getElementsByTagName('tr')`

Answer (score 0):

Although the user Isaac seems to be inactive here comes a possible solution.

My initial code:

```
 <table align="center" border="1" cellpadding="15" cellspacing="10" >
 <tr>
   <th colspan="7"> Headline </th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>colmun</td>
   <td>column</td>
   <td>column</td>
   <td>column</td>
   <td>column</td>
   <td>column</td>
   <td>column</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>colmun</td>
   <td>column</td>
   <td>column</td>
   <td>column</td>
   <td>column</td>
   <td>column</td>
   <td>column</td>
 </tr>     
 </table>
```

The task: removing the rows except the first.

What I had tried before:

```
var tableObj = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
var coloumns = tableObj.getElementsByTagName("tr");
for(var i=0; i < coloumns.length; i++ )
{
  coloumns[i].parentNode.removeChild(coloumns[i]);
}
```

And I didn't get the expected result.

When I found the post from [meze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/265712/meze), I replaced the the `for()` loop by `do{} while()`:

```
var tableObj = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
var coloumns = tableObj.getElementsByTagName("tr");
do {
  coloumns[0].parentNode.removeChild(coloumns[0]);
} while (coloumns.length > 1)
```

and so I got the expected result.